# isolate networks in hyperv

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, isolated-network

I would like to isolate my pc LAN from my servers LAN.
All my servers are virtual machines in a windows2008r2 hyperv cluster (2nodes).
I thought about create a rras virtual machine and play with my 2 procurve (vlans).
Is there another way ?
My goal is to prevent someone to put manually an ip address of one of my server on his computer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Network Cards (and thus multiple Networks in Hyper-V) or the use of Hyper-V Level controlle VLANs (so the VM never sees which VLAN she is in, just the rare packets). THe later is what I use to separate about a dozen Networks on the infrastructure Level.

Comment: do you mean i don't need a routeur ?

Answer (score 0):

If your procurves support ip routing, you don't need to setup RRAS. 
If you are only going to run servers on the Hyper-V hosts, you don't even need to change anything on the host - just add the physical ports to the correct vlan and set your IP addresses accordingly.

This is "simple" but may not allow for future needs if you needed multiple VLAN's off a single physical NIC (or NIC team).

Comment: Yes, i only run servers in the hosts, and so i can just add the physical ports to a vlan but how do i make the routing ? a physical routeur ? a rras VM ?

Comment: Well, happens i have a lot of htem around as well as Switches that can route statically. EVERY time you ahve multiple Networks you Need a router. Physical or virtual.

Comment: Most of the Procurve switches I've worked with will support static IP Routing and can be used as a basic layer3 switch and will work fine so long as you aren't doing anything complicated. If you start pushing past that and want to start running BGP/OSPF(or other dynamic routing protocols), you'll probably need to step up either hardware or licensing on the switch. @TomTom you only need a router if you want the networks to talk to eachother. :) For example, a dedicated iSCSI network doesn't need to be routed.